# Basic Probability Question X ~

Tags: probability

A little stuck on these questions. Help would be much appreciated.

A) If $X \sim \textrm{Bin}(2, p)$ find a value of $p$ for which $\textrm{P}_r ( W = 4) = 0.3432$, where $W = (x+1)^2$. State your answer to 2 decimal places.

My Solution: If $W = 4$, then $X = 1$ from the given formula. Hence we can assume $\textrm{P}_r(X = 1) = \textrm{P}_r(W = 4) = 0.3432$.

Now substituting these values into the Binomial formula:

$\textrm{P}_r(X = 1 ) = \left[\frac{2!}{[(2-1)!\cdot 1!]}\right] * p^1(1-p)^{(2-1)} = 0.3432$, so $2p(1-p) = 0.3432$. From this we get two solutions, i.e. $p = 0.22$ and $p = 0.78$.

B) If $X \sim N(3,3)$ and $Y \sim N(-0.5,0.25)$ are independent, find the probability that $W = X +2Y$ is negative. State your answer to 4 decimal places.

Not sure where to start with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Find $W=X+2Y$ in the form of $N(a,b)$.
Then the probability is$$\textrm{P}(W<0)=\textrm{P}\left(Z<\frac{0-a}{\sqrt{b}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Ok so using the given formulas: 
a = 3 +2(-0.5) = 2

b = 3+2^2*0.25 = 4

W ~B(2, 4)

Pr(W) < 0 -> Pr(Z < (0-a)/(sqrt(b))

=Pr(Z < (0-2)/(sqrt(4))

=Pr(Z < -1)

= 0.1587

Is this correct?