# Binomial distribution question - solving for p

Tags: statistics

If $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(2,p)$, find a value of p for which $Pr(W=4)=0.3432$, where $W=(X+1)^2$

My thought process:

Find $X$ when $W=4$,

$$4=(X+1)^2$$

Therefore $X=1$

Then solve binomial:

$$0.3432=\binom{2}{1}(p^1)(1-p)^{2-1}$$

I get two answers, $p=0.22$ or $0.78$

Is this correct?

Comment: It seems like duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414358/basic-probability-question-x three hours ago.

Comment: Why the deliberate duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, while the  index for the binomial expression is a bit off, I believe it is just a typo.

$$0.3432 = \binom{2}{1}p^{\color{blue}1}(1-p)^1$$

$$p(1-p)=0.1716$$

$ p = 0.22$ or $p=0.78$.